# thumbnails on ubuntu 14.04 with pageres and some other issue in mac

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I want to take snapshot of webpage...but when i load in Ubuntu its not loaded at all...it stops in the middle.

```
  url = 'https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/index.html?responderOn=true#/category/AC';
 var options = {delay:2};
var pageres = new Pageres(options)
    .src(url, ['1280x1024'], {crop: true})
    .run(function(error, items){
        console.log(items);

        items[0].on('data', function (data) {
            bufferData.push(data);
        });

        items[0].on('end', function () {
            deferred.resolve(Buffer.concat(bufferData));
        });
    });

pageres.on('warn', function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

but in Mac its different issue, but eventually i can generate in mac or windows.

even on ubuntu i can generate snapshot of other pages like google.com or any other.

can someone help in understanding why the phantomjs does not load all relative urls in ubuntu but it loads in mac??

Thanks
Moyeen

Comment: Have you tried a higher delay?

Comment: I did...it just cuts the request....in the middle due to console error..where as i dont see those console error on mac..

Comment: What error is this? Please include everything that is necessary to diagnose the problem into your question.

Comment: Error: found in negative cache: 'sap/ui/core/Core.js' from undefined/sap/ui/core/Core.js: The given language does not adhere to BCP-47.

  https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:80 in a1
  https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:80
  https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js:144
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'new sap.m.Shell')

  https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/index.html?responderOn=true#/category/AC:27

Comment: Even testing this with phantomjs 1.9.8 itself throws this error

Comment: `var page = require('webpage').create();
page.open('https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/m/demokit/cart/index.html?responderOn=true#/category/AC', function() {
  page.render('github.png');
  phantom.exit();
});`